# Asp.Net 4 Response.Cookies.Add does not add cookie to users machine

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I am trying to setup a basic Form Authentication using ASP.NET 4.

I know my validation code (code that checks if the username and password is correct) is working because after if the user enters invalid information the ReturnLable tells them so. However if they enter the correct information, they are redirected to the restricted page with a 403 – Forbidden error. When I check the shell:cookie path no cookie has been written even though I added it to the collection “Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);”

```
protected void Submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Email.Text = Email.Text.Trim();
    Password.Text = Password.Text.Trim();
    if (IsValid(Email.Text, Password.Text)) //user exists
    {
        FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
            1,
            Email.Text,
            DateTime.Now,
            DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(50),
            RememberMe.Checked,
            "user",
            FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);
        string hashCookies = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, hashCookies);

        Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
    else
    {
        ReturnLable.Text = "<font color=red> Username/Password Incorrect Please Try Again </font>";
        ReturnLable.Visible = true;
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289495%28v=vs.71%29.aspx):

> If you do not set the cookie's expiration, the cookie is created but
>   it is not stored on the user's hard disk. Instead, the cookie is
>   maintained as part of the user's session information. When the user
>   closes the browser or if the session times out, the cookie is
>   discarded.

Thus, a cookie could be successfully set, alive and well in the browser, but have no corresponding file in the "cookies" folder on the hard drive.

Comment: Glad this resolved the issue! If you click the checkmark-shaped image next to this answer, it will "accept" it as the answer that solved the issue. Accepting answers is good stackoverflow-citizenship.

Comment: To clarify, this means adding cookie.Expires = <datetime>

Answer (score 0):

make sure that  Enable anonymous access is disabled on IIS and Integrated Windows security is enabled

Comment: disabling Anonymous access bar access to all pages, i want the user to be able to see most of the a fit of them I am restricting acsess only to certain directories which I do in my web.config file. Either way when I write a cookie with Response.Cookies.Add I expect to see it in my shell:cookies folder which right now I am not seeing

Comment: thank you for you answer, the issue was that i wasn't setting an expiration date in the cookie